# WebStorm - Unresolved variable or type - Sails / module.export

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, warnings, webstorm

Trying to fix WebStorm v11.0.4 warnings in JavaScript. Lots of `unresolved variable or type` errors for custom types in SailsJS application, such as this one:

[image: unresolvedVariable01]

I already enabled Node.js in WebStorm. Also, don't know if it is linked, but cannot see "Node Globals" as a library to enable (see pictures below).

[image: unresolvedVariable02]

[image: unresolvedVariable03]

Now, I'm clearly not a JavaScript pro. There is a file called `DataService.js` in the `./api/services/DataService.js` folder, but even in there, the exact same error occur, and the `DataService` type appears to be defined nowhere :/

Any idea, if there is a clean way to get rid of those warnings (ideally making WebStorm aware of those types) or if I just need to ignore them and live with it? Is this a global type defined in Sails or somewhere else?

**Edit**: One solution that works is in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403689/sails-js-intellisense-in-webstorm). 
But I'm not good enough in JS to understand the impact of this solution.

Thanks!

Comment: "Node Globals" has been merged with "Node.js Core", so enabling Node.js Core library is enough to get intellisense for core modules.

Comment: Duplicate of [Webstorm 7 cannot recognize node API methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532660/webstorm-7-cannot-recognize-node-api-methods)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Seems you need to enable Node Core library (as lena also commented), 
**Within WebStorm:**

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM
2. Make sure that 'Node.js Core library is enabled' by pressing Enable button.
3. Click OK for saving settings.

**NOTE:** Make sure you do it within 'Settings' and not only in 'Default Settings'

Comment: In 2018 and later WebStorm versions 'Node.js Core library is enabled' is replaced by 'Coding assistance for Node.js'

Comment: in 2023 "Coding assistance for Node.js", but to work I deactivated save and enable, work! :S