# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component in Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not understanding why I am getting this error message in the console. I currently have a function component called Home set up the same way and I am not getting the error message for that component.

Here is the code to my App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Resume from './components/pages/Resume';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
            <Route path='/resume' component={Resume} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code to my Home, which does not get an error message.

```js
import React from 'react';

import HeroSection from '../HeroSection';
import About from './About';
import Skills from './Skills';
import Footer from '../Footer';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <HeroSection />
      <Skills />
      <About />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

I am getting an error message from this component Resume. The page currently renders fine, but I get the error in the console.

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Resume() {
    return <div>Resume</div>
}
```

Comment: Can you try this
import React from "react";

export default  Resume = ()  =>  <div>Resume</div>

Comment: My IDE complains that Resume is an unresolved variable or type. Do you mean like this?
const Resume = () => <div>Resume</div>
export default Resume;
That also has the same result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853027/webstorm-unresolved-variable-or-type-sails-module-export did you try this ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that in your Resume file, you are not returning anything, add a `return(<div>Resume</div>)` and the problem will be solved.

I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: I am sorry yes there is a return statement I did not write it correctly on here. My page is rendering fine, but I am getting the error in the console.